# Java xml to JTree with unknown categories

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree

Hi I want to make a JTree from a xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root name="Passwoerter">
    <use name="LoL" username="hallo" password="asdasd" note="asdasdasdads"/>
    <category name="Mail">
        <use name="GMail" username="hallo" password="asdasd" note="sadasdasdads"/>
        <category name="Webmail">
            <use name="Yahoo" username="hallo" password="asdasd" note="asdasdadsasd"/>
        </category>
    </category>
</root>
```

with that structure you can have endless sub categories in categories.

I read the xml file and make an ArrayList which has all the information 
the Class Category has:

```
String name
Category parent
ArrayList<Category> categories
ArrayList<Usage> usages
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create the TreeNodes with a unknown number of categories.

Edit:
I don't know how many categorys the user created but i need to create the tree.
So if the user created 100 sub categories in one category i stil want to show the tree correctly.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Dynamically Changing a Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic). Further down it shows how to add a new *node* to the *tree* via an *add button*. I think the logic can be adjusted to what you need, you will be doing it programatcally rather than a button click?

Comment: If i understood your situation correctly, I am confused as to why you say *The problem is that I don't know how to create the TreeNodes with a unknown number of categories.* Surely once you have read in the data via the XML you are able to get a count of the number of tags for a certain label you parsed? Than you will technically at runtime not know the amount of categories, but after the XML is processed you will... than you create the JTree if you get my drift.